# Creating a density plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I am new in R and I am trying to create a density plot.
I am looking to create a plot based on some regression analysis I have done earlier. So, basically, I want to see the relationship of Z to a,b and c variables that I have. All variables have values that range between 0 and 1 (numeric).

I have been trying to use ggplot to do the plot using the following code:

```
     dataset$test <- data.frame(a, b, c)
     ggplot(dataset, aes(Z, colour = test)) + geom_density()
```

I am not sure how I can group the a,b,c variables into 1 so I can use that in the *colour* of the ggplot function (see test variable)

When I run the ggplot I get this error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (417): x, colour.

Can anyone help me develop this plot?

Thanks!

[See the sample image of what I'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfvpC.jpg)

Comment: It always helps to include the dataset in the question, or if it is too big, generate some sample. Can you run 'dput(dataset)` and add the output to your question?

Comment: However my guess is that you are doing some wrong in the first line when creating `dataset$test`

Comment: Hi Mikey, thanks for answering.
I'm afraid the dput output is also too big. Is there something specific you need to know so I can tell you? But yes, I have a strong feeling that my test variable is not as it should be. So the issue I guess is to group the 3 variables into 1?

Comment: Are you sure that density is what you're looking for? I can see you want to see relationships between numeric variables. Density will give you the distribution of a specific variable.

Comment: Hi Antoni,

I have added a sample image of what I am trying to create. Please see the link above. I want to see the density of the data, so how the Z data distributes across those 3 variables in one chart.

Comment: I got it. I'll post a solution with an example dataset that looks like yours so you can adjust the code (minor changes) to achieve what you want. The (density) plot you posted shows that those variables are not between 0 and 1 though. It's important to see how your dataset looks like. Can you get a random sample of 20 rows of your original dataset and `dput` that?

Comment: Hi Antoni, thanks for the code. Yes, the image I uploaded is just a sample and has different scales. However, I want both of my scales to be between 0 and 1 since all my data are like that. As I said, I'm fairly new in R, not sure how I can produce what you ask for. My dataset is quite big with 417 observations and 33 variables.The code you posted works based on what I want to do, yet I still need to fix the scales etc.

Comment: Assuming that your original dataset is `df` do this: `library(dplyr);
df_sample = df %>% sample_n(20);
dput(df_sample)` and then copy and paste the `structure(...)` it returns somewhere in your question. Then I will adjust my solution to your dataset.

Comment: `structure(list(pri1994v.new = c(0.971124242839577, 0.647744329408573, 
    0.394154485216103, 0.669032214778841, 0.558895272448545, 
    0.87115009526459, 0.49285342359918, 0.540861377691693, 0.607204753550897, 
    0.670138114840184, 0.577973091496735, 0.749688203651789, 
    0.450595315118593, 0.605513949419096, 0.821524305486969, 
    0.710100280689779, 0.39947194003917, 0.456354118474409, 0.678656882405299, 
    0.630717334138923), pan1994v.new = c(0.293603032268667, -0.83710403598108, 
    -0.442664864917589, 0.935217001823215, -0.850628344666785`
Again, it returns a lot of data

Comment: It should return 20 rows x the number of columns you have. Comments have a character limit, so you can't post the whole thing. However, I think that you should be able to adjust my code to your dataset. Also, think how 33 density plots are going to look in one graph. You won't be able to see clearly each one of those.

Comment: My entire dataset has 33 variables, but I only want to use 3 of those for this plot. So basically like the graph I posted above, but with the scales being 0-1 (forgot to change them in the photo). Thanks!

Comment: If the scales are 0-1 already then you don't need to do anything more. Just create `df` to be the dataset of interest (i,e, original dataset with only those 3 columns) and use the code I posted. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example dataset
df = data.frame(a = rnorm(50, 5, 6),
                b = rnorm(50, 0, 1),
                c = runif(50,0,1))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  gather(var, Z) %>%                                  # reshape dataset
  ggplot(aes(Z, fill=var))+geom_density(alpha = 0.3)  # plot data
```